# Capistrano deployment behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have this deploy.rb

```
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_db', 'deploy:symlink_email'
after 'deploy:setup', 'setup:create_db_configuration', 'setup:create_email_configuration'


namespace :deploy do
  desc "Symlinks the email.yml"
  task :symlink_email, :roles => :app do
    puts "##Sybolic Link the email.yml"
    run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/email.yml #{release_path}/config/email.yml"
  end

desc "Symlinks the database.yml"
  task :symlink_db, :roles => :app do
    puts "##Sybolic Link the database.yml"
    run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
```

But when I deploy, after the deploy:update_code it starts with

```
2013-07-27 03:30:30 executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
```

then

```
2013-07-27 03:30:32 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
```

And when execution

```
executing "cd -- /home/ubuntu/deployments/saleshub/releases/20130727013023 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets rake assets:precompile"
```

It fails, because the symbolic links were not created yet. How do I make sure the my tasks to create the symlinks before compiling the assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before 'deploy:assets:precompile', 'deploy:symlink_db', 'deploy:symlink_email'
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed to 
after 'deploy:finalize_update', 'deploy:symlink_db', 'deploy:symlink_email'